# how to identify or visualize group of nodes in a directed network graph using cytoscape

Tags: r, cytoscape

I have a network table containing three columns as indicated below in R code

```
data <- data.frame(from = letters[1:20], to= LETTERS[1:20],
                   group = rep(c("normal", "middle", "high","veryhigh"),times =c(5,5,5,5)))
```

I did export the data to Cytoscape app for visualizing the network.
However, I tried a lot but could not able to make the following.

1. How can I give colors for the nodes in column **"from"** and column **"to"** and how I can
   differetly the nodes in the from **column** from **to** column?
2. How can I see the nodes of the four groups in different colors based on the **group** column in one network?

I would appricate it if some could give some tips here!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question.  Once this is imported into Cytoscape, you should be able to use the Styles panel to color your nodes using a discrete mapper.  I'm assuming you're talking about Cytoscape desktop, here, right?

-- scooter